# SQL Create or Replace Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a oracle database and we have been running into problems with our build and install procedures where when we update the table schema (add, modify columns, triggers, etc) it doesn't always get deployed to all the instances.

Right now we handle schema updates by putting notes on the install steps for the build to run alter table commands, etc.  But these always assume you are going from the last build (i.e. build 3 is installed and we are going to 4).  If 1 is installed, there might be alter scripts going from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, then 3 to 4.  So this is a giant pain of a manual process that we often mess up and miss an altar.

Is there a easy way to do a "create or replace" on a table without dropping it and losing data?  Essentially we want to compare the current table to what it should be and update it.  We do not want to backup the table, drop it, create it, and then restore it.

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Essentially we want to compare the current table to what it should be and update it"

Assuming you have a good source version that you want to use to update the other instances, you can Toad's schema compare (you need the DBA Admin module or Toad Xpert Edition) and generate the scripts needed to update a single table, a set of tables, or whatever list of objects you choose.

I would say that the scripts should still be checked/verified before running against the target instance.  Some changes may be best handled in a different way (rename a column vs drop/create for example).  So be careful.

One more note that others will probably bring up is that this problem shows definite holes in your company's change management process (which is a much bigger topic than this question).

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for a creative programmatic solution to our problem, but you are right.  The problem is rooted in the change management process and can't be automated because of things like column renames (probably why there is no "create or replace" for tables).  I think what I really need is to change our process so that 'install notes' become baselined scripts and then a stick to hit my developers when they run alters on the database outside of a normal install.